# for each in MS SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

`Employees(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeStatus, BasicSalary)` and

`EmployeePayroll (PayrollID, EmployeeID, VoucherNo, BasicSalary, SalaryMonth)`

I want to make a `for each` loop for every employee in the first table so that I can insert dummy data like `(0, EmployeeID,0 ,0 ,0)` into the second table.

I tried to make it with a `for` loop but I could not make it, so is there a `for each` loop in MS SQL Server??

Comment: SQL is a set-based language. You want to avoid procedural code like for-loops.

Comment: Inserting dummy data into SQL table?? Something dirty smells here... SQL is not MS Excel :-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeePayroll
SELECT
  0,EmployeeID ,0,0,0
FROM
  Employees
```

You can check for the existance of the record before inserting it by appending:

```
WHERE
  ID NOT IN
  (
     SELECT
       EmployeeID
     FROM
       EmployeePayroll
  )
```

Comment: thanks my friend this code will fix current problem for sure , I ask Allah to save Syria  ,but is can i used For each because i write a small example only just to make it easy but the real code is very long and there are more than 3 functions to be used inside that code .

so is there For each loop in sql server or do i have to use Loop only?

Comment: @HAJJAJ: May Allah save Yemen too my friend. I suggest using [cursors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) to loop on your rows.

Answer (score 29):

If you **really** require a loop, you can use a cursor.  They are **horribly inefficient**, so you should avoid unless you absolutely require it:

```
DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT EmployeeID
    FROM Employees

DECLARE @id Int

-- Open the cursor
OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EmployeePayroll
    SELECT 0, @id, 0, 0, 0

    -- do other stuff

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id
END

-- Close and deallocate the cursor
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Comment: +1 for the performance warning: but "not very efficient" is an understatement; if you want to bring you server to its knees, use cursors.

Comment: Right you are.  I've corrected my grave mistake to "horribly inefficient" ;)

Comment: @DavidDuffett - When does it become horribly inefficient ? I have only 10-100 rows which come from this query - `EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\Files', 10, 1
`

Comment: @blasto - they certainly have their uses, but can cause perf related problems if abused.  this answer is better than any way I could explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/747376/91619

Answer (score 5):

This is the one way to achieve your requirement using While loop & Temp table variable,

The sample query is given below,

```
--: Get the Employees table data & insert this to temp table variable
Declare @TempEmpTbl Table (RowId int identity, EmployeeID int, EmployeeName nvarchar(100), EmployeeStatus int, BasicSalary int);
Insert into @TempEmpTbl Select * from Employees;

--: temp variables
Declare @TempEmpCount Int = (Select Count(RowId) From @TempEmpTbl);
Declare @MinCount Int = 1;
Declare @GetEmpId int;

--: while loop for EmployeePayroll tbl insertion based on Employees data
While(@TempEmpCount >= @MinCount)
Begin
    Set @GetEmpId = (Select EmployeeID From @TempEmpTbl Where RowId = @MinCount);   
    Insert into EmployeePayroll values (0, @GetEmpId,0 ,0 ,0)
    Set @MinCount = @MinCount + 1;
End
```

Note : Suppose the employee record is already there, we can able to update EmployeePayroll records from within this while loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO EmployeePayroll
SELECT
 0,E.EmployeeID ,0,0,0
FROM
Employees E
WHERE 
NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT
       1
     FROM
       EmployeePayroll WHERE EmployeeID = E.Id
)
```

Hope this helps

This is most optimized way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

**HI**

> USE Default constraints for the column which needs to be zero
>
> payrollID,VoucherNo, BasicSalary,
>   Salary-Month
>
> insert the EmployeeID  for the same
>   and use the above mentioned concept

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a decent way for a foreach loop in SQL and came up with this easy code

```
SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id),*
INTO #Locations
FROM [dbo].[Location]

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT
SET @MaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #Locations)

DECLARE @Iter INT
SET @Iter = (SELECT MIN(RowNum) FROM #Locations)



WHILE @Iter <= @MaxRownum
BEGIN
DECLARE @currentCountry varchar(250)
DECLARE @locId int
SET @currentCountry = ( SELECT Country 
                        FROM #Locations
                        WHERE RowNum = @Iter)

SET @LocId = (  SELECT Id 
                FROM #Locations
                WHERE RowNum = @Iter)



    -- run your operation here
Update [dbo].[Location]
SET CountryId  = (SELECT (Id) FROM [dbo].[Site] WHERE [dbo].[Site].Name = @currentCountry)
WHERE [dbo].[Location].Id = @locId


    SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
END

DROP TABLE #Locations
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **`Cross Apply`**. This is the best alternate for cursor and looping. 
Mover over if you compare the execution plan of cross apply with other methods you will notice its noticeably faster

http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-2005/cross-apply-explained