# Creating Ids for a block of information based on a specific column filter

Tags: sql-server

On my table, I have 4 columns. I need to create a procedure (or a simple query) that creates Ids for a block of information based on a specific column filter.

Better explaining,

I have this information (note the 2nd and 3rd field):

```
PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES|TEMP_NUMBER|TYPE|_Date
18953|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 09:01:00.000
18954|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 09:01:00.000
7847|NULL|BBBB|2017-06-26 09:01:00.000
7848|NULL|BBBB|2017-06-26 09:01:00.000
7849|NULL|BBBB|2017-06-26 09:02:00.000
13444|NULL||2017-06-28 10:06:00.000
13445|NULL||2017-06-28 10:07:00.000
13447|NULL||2017-06-28 10:07:00.000
14953|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:16:00.000
14954|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:16:00.000
14955|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:17:00.000
14956|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:17:00.000
15134|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:46:00.000
15135|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:46:00.000
15138|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:47:00.000
15139|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:47:00.000
15140|NULL|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:47:00.000
```

I need to get this (note the 2nd and 3rd field):

```
PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES|TEMP_NUMBER|TYPE|_Date
18953|1|AAAA|2017-06-28 09:01:00.000
18954|1|AAAA|2017-06-28 09:01:00.000
7847|NULL|BBBB|2017-06-26 09:01:00.000
7848|NULL|BBBB|2017-06-26 09:01:00.000
7849|NULL|BBBB|2017-06-26 09:02:00.000
13444|NULL||2017-06-28 10:06:00.000
13445|NULL||2017-06-28 10:07:00.000
13447|NULL||2017-06-28 10:07:00.000
14953|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:16:00.000
14954|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:16:00.000
14955|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:17:00.000
14956|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:17:00.000
15134|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:46:00.000
15135|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:46:00.000
15138|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:47:00.000
15139|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:47:00.000
15140|2|AAAA|2017-06-28 14:47:00.000
```

The order by for this table will be:

```
order by th._Date,tc.PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES
```

Note: In my poor example, I made an order by on _Date but I forgot to do on the PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLE. The correct is order by Date (column 4) and ID (column 1).

I just care if the 3rd column = AAAA. If it is an AAAA I should create a number (an identifier for this block of information). In my case, I created the ID 1 for the first AAAA block and the ID 2 for the second block of AAAA. I don't care about <> than AAAA.

So, any ideas of how should I approach this? My first ideas was going line by line and check if the next is the same, if yes, I keep going until I find a <> one. But as pointed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856073/for-each-in-ms-sql-server), this will be really slow. Also, I am more familiar with C# which is pretty simple to go line by line using a foreach loop, I am not sure how simple is in Sequel.

Comment: Since order is not defined in the table.  How is this data set ordered?  It's important to know because the 3rd column may really need 6 AAAA's at the top set and 3 at the bottom.  Without an order this can't be done.

Comment: What `group by` or `order by` criteria?

Comment: How you are defining ORDER? On what column?

Comment: I edited my question to explain this part, I totally forgot!

Comment: Your sample data doesn't ordered by `th._Date,tc.PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES`

Comment: In that case your will get first with BBBB block next with null's and then with AAAA with single block... How you define two blocks in AAAA?

Comment: @RuslanK., no, it is not. I am making the sample data in the correct order by. In my example, it is only ordered by Date. I will post the updated data in a few minutes - sorry about that.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, thinking line by line... I keep going each line, if it is an AAAA, I created 1 ID. If changes for anything else than AAAA, it should be a new ID. If line 0 = AAAA, it will contain ID=1. If line 1 = AAAA, it will contain ID=1. If line 3 = AAAX, it will contain NULL (this break my sequence of AAAA). If line 4 = AAAA this will be a new ID because I had a break in the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (SQL 2012+):

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE(
    PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES INT, T INT, [TYPE] VARCHAR(256), _Date DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES
(18953, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 09:01:00.000'),
(18954, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 09:01:00.000'),
(7847, NULL,  'BBBB', '2017-06-28 09:01:00.000'),
(7848, NULL,  'BBBB', '2017-06-28 09:01:00.000'),
(7849, NULL,  'BBBB', '2017-06-28 09:02:00.000'),
(13444, NULL,     '', '2017-06-28 14:06:00.000'),
(13445, NULL,     '', '2017-06-28 14:07:00.000'),
(13447, NULL,     '', '2017-06-28 14:07:00.000'),
(14953, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 12:16:00.000'),
(14954, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 12:16:00.000'),
(14955, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 12:17:00.000'),
(14956, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 14:17:00.000'),
(15134, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 14:46:00.000'),
(15135, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 14:46:00.000'),
(15138, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 14:47:00.000'),
(15139, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 14:47:00.000'),
(15140, NULL, 'AAAA', '2017-06-28 14:47:00.000')

DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(256) = 'AAAA';
WITH Marked AS (
    SELECT PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES, [TYPE], _Date,
        TypeChanged = IIF(LAG([TYPE]) OVER (ORDER BY _Date,PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES) = [TYPE] OR [TYPE] <> @Type, 0, 1)
    FROM @YourTable
)
SELECT PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES, [TYPE], _Date,
    TEMP_NUMBER = IIF([TYPE] = @TYPE, SUM(TypeChanged) OVER (ORDER BY _Date,PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES), NULL)
FROM Marked
WHERE TYPE = @Type
ORDER BY _Date,PK_ID_TBL_POINTS_AND_CYCLES
```

Comment: How should I change your query to only created this "Block IDs" for "AAAA"  (3rd column from my example)? I tried to use a where clause in the 1st select, but it returns the same "Block Id" for everything. If I try a where in the second Select, I get "Block Id" with gap IDs. I.e. 1,4,8 and not in sequence. This is more a silly correction but this will work for my problem.

Comment: You should filter second SELECT, I edited my answer to fix error

Comment: Still, I have the same issue. For the first block (Type = '') the TEMP_NUMBER=0. Then, a sequence is being created, but still, the sequence of number is being based on all the types and not only = 'AAAA'. For example, the first block (Type = '') = 0; the second block (Type = 'AAAA') = 1; the third block (Type = 'AAXX') = 3

Comment: I've created test table and set TEST_NUMBER = NULL if type <> 'AAAA', let's view my answer with test data

Answer (score 0):

You can query as below:

```
;With cte as (
    Select *, Rnk = Sum(ChangeIdentifier) over(order by [date]) from (
        Select *, ChangeIdentifier = case when [type] <> lag([type]) over(order by [date]) then 1 else 0 end from #tempdata
    ) a 
) Select dense_rank() over(order by case when [Type] = 'AAAA' then Rnk else 0 end)-1, * from cte
order by [date]
```