# Use SELECT results as a variable in a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I've searched here and elsewhere, and haven't found an answer yet. Hope I didn't miss it.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2.

I have n specific databases on my server (there are other DBs as well, but I'm only interested in some of them)

Each of these databases has a table within it, which all have the same name. The only difference is the DB name. I want to aggregate these tables together to make one big table on a different database (different to the other DBs).

I can get the db names from the results of a query.

N is unknown.

Is a loop the way to go about this?

I was thinking something along the lines of the following pseudocode:

```
Set @dbnames = SELECT DISTINCT dbname FROM MyServer.dbo.MyTable

For each @name in @dbnames
    INSERT INTO ADifferentDB.dbo.MyOtherTable
    SELECT * FROM @name.dbo.table
Next name
```

(Clearly I'm new to using SQL variable as well, as you can see)

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server expert (I use pgsql), but you'll want to look at [`EXECUTE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).  Since the source table name is going to vary, you'll have to create each `INSERT` query on the fly as a string, and execute it using `EXECUTE()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first problem is about iterating the databases: you cand do that with a cursor

Then you have another problem, executing a query where part of it is variable (database's name). You can do that with `execute` function.

All that is something similar to this:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE my_db_cursor CURSOR
            FOR SELECT DISTINCT dbname FROM MyServer.dbo.MyTable
OPEN my_db_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM my_db_cursor 
INTO @dbname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO ADifferentDB.dbo.MyOtherTable
                   SELECT * FROM ' + @dbname + '.dbo.table'
    EXECUTE(@query)  

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_db_cursor 
    INTO @dbname
END
CLOSE my_db_cursor 
DEALLOCATE my_db_cursor
```

Comment: @tkrex Glad it was useful. Remember Cursors are very pricey in terms of resources; you should be careful about using them. They are OK for one-time operations like this case though. You can take a look at this if you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743183/what-is-wrong-with-cursors

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do is define a `CURSOR` for row-level operation.  here is some [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: I had never even heard of cursors before!  (Reveals how much of a SQL noob i am, i suppose.) This looks incredibly useful.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`sp_MSForEachDB`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB '
-- Include only the databases you care about.
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM MySever.dbo.MyTable
    WHERE dbname = ''?''
)
    -- Exit if the database is not in your table.
    RETURN

-- Otherwise, perform your insert.
INSERT INTO ADifferentDB.dbo.MyOtherTable
SELECT * FROM ?.dbo.table
'
```

In this case, `?` is a token that is replaced with each database on the server.